# Adjusting SeekBar length

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I have an Android app with the following kotlin function:

```
fun setAdjustBars() {
    val clrSetBarR = SeekBar(this)
    val clrSetBarG = SeekBar(this)
    val clrSetBarB = SeekBar(this)

    clrSetBarR.thumbTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(255,0,0))
    clrSetBarG.thumbTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(0,255,0))
    clrSetBarB.thumbTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(0,0,255))

    val sideColrVal = 77
    clrSetBarR.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(255,sideColrVal,sideColrVal))
    clrSetBarG.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(sideColrVal,255,sideColrVal))
    clrSetBarB.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(sideColrVal,sideColrVal,255))

    val constrSet = ConstraintSet()
    val seekBarsArray = arrayOf(clrSetBarR,clrSetBarG,clrSetBarB)

    seekBarsArray.map {
        it.id = View.generateViewId()
        constraintLayout?.addView(it)
        it.rotation = 270.0F
        it.max = 255
    }

    constrSet.clone(constraintLayout)

    seekBarsArray.map {
        constrSet.connect(it.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, deviceFrameID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        constrSet.setMargin(it.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 50)
    }

    val sideShift = 150
    constrSet.connect(clrSetBarR.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, deviceFrameID, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
    constrSet.setMargin(clrSetBarR.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, sideShift)
    constrSet.connect(clrSetBarG.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, deviceFrameID, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
    constrSet.connect(clrSetBarG.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, deviceFrameID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
    constrSet.connect(clrSetBarB.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, deviceFrameID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
    constrSet.setMargin(clrSetBarB.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, sideShift)

    constrSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
}
```

The role of the function is to lay out three vertical SeekBar objects at the bottom of the display. As one can see in the screenshot below it does its job. The one problem I have is that the length (height) of the bars is far too short. How can I modify my code to get bars with proper length? (Say a few centimeters instead of one millimeter or so as is is now)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to change the `width` of the `SeekBar` to adjust its length. Change its width after adding it to the layout.

```
seekBarsArray.map {
    it.id = View.generateViewId()
    constraintLayout?.addView(it)
        
    val params = it.layoutParams
    params.width = 350
    it.layoutParams = params
        
    it.max = 255
    it.rotation = 270f
}
```

---

As your views are at the bottom of the screen, rotating it, could move views out of the screen. You may want to change the pivot points of the views before rotating them.

Comment: Your solution works.I change the value passed to constrSet.setMargin(it.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 50), 300 instead of 50. And I need to make some adjustment at the value of sideShift (end of the function), I suppose it is due to the way and order the operations are performed. When you mention "change the pivot points", I understand the idea, but how do you do that?

Comment: before rotation use `it.pivotX` and `it.pivotY` to change `x` or `y` pivot points respectively (`it` is the view). Now `rotation` would use these points as anchors. `Note - pivot points are relative to the view. (0, 0) would use the left most and top most point of the view.`